# How would one bind two different button click events to the same label, namely "<Button-1>" and "<Double-Button1>" to same label?

Tags: python, python-2.7, events, tkinter

So, i know there has got to be a way to do this iv'e literally been trying all day to figure a solution and this is the closest i've come to getting it. The code works but the flaw is that it never reaches the else if statement because whatever button click is first in the statement will always be True hence it will never reach else if. Is their some way to combine the first two statements of my code into one because i believe that would solve it? This is using the tkinter GUI.

```
    self.label1.bind("<Double-Button-1>",self._two_click)
    self.label1.bind("<Button-1>", self._two_click)

def  _two_click(self,event):
    if self.label1.bind("<Button-1>"):
        self.label1.configure(self.my_timeBB())
    elif self.label1.bind("<Double-Button-1>"):
        self.label1.configure(text="Blue")
```

Comment: You have `event`, print it to see what you get.

Comment: Sorry, In normal GUI you have a lot information in `event` but Tkinter is strange and there is no information about double or single click. See: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm

Comment: But maybe I have other solution.

Comment: this is what i get when i print event tkinter event instance at 0 x 0000003473

Comment: See link in previous comment - there are more info about events.

Comment: Yeah ive ready that page like 40 to 50 times probably

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use extra argument in function to recognize click.

BTW: you can always bind `<Button-1>` and `<Double-Button1>` to one widget but with different functions ?

```
import Tkinter as tk

def test(event, extra=None):
    print extra

master = tk.Tk()

b1 = tk.Button(master, text="QUIT", command=master.destroy, width=20, heigh=5)
b1.pack()

b2 = tk.Label(master, text="OK", width=20, heigh=5)
b2.pack()

b2.bind('<Double-Button-1>', lambda event:test(event,101))

b2.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event:test(event,1))
b2.bind('<Button-2>', lambda event:test(event,2))
b2.bind('<Button-3>', lambda event:test(event,3))

master.mainloop()
```

But I see one (big) problem - when I try to make double-click with my mouse I always get two text - first for single-click and second for double-click.

The only solution can be measure time between click and decide whether choose single or double click. But probably it will need to use `after()` too.

---

**EDIT:**

run only single or double clik

```
import Tkinter as tk

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

single = False

def test(event, extra=None):
    global single

    #print 'event-num:', event.num
    #print 'extra:', extra

    if extra == 1:
        single = True
        master.after(200, single_click)
    elif extra == 101:
        single = False
        click('double click')

def single_click():
    global single

    if single:
        single = False
        click('single click')

def click(msg):
    print 'It was', msg

#----------------------------------------------------------------------

master = tk.Tk()

b1 = tk.Button(master, text="QUIT", command=master.destroy, width=20, heigh=5)
b1.pack()

b2 = tk.Label(master, text="OK", width=20, heigh=5)
b2.pack()

b2.bind('<Double-Button-1>', lambda event:test(event,101))
b2.bind('<Button-1>', lambda event:test(event,1))

master.mainloop()
```

Comment: hmmm, i dont really think that is an option for me here considering the purpose of what im trying to make will what using two different functions to same label like you said?

Comment: okay just tried the two functions method and it works but only for a second and then it switches back to button-1 hmmm and return "break" doesnt seem to help

Comment: If you will use `if/else` as in `_two_click` to split two types of click than there will be no difference to use separated functions. But if you have common code for both types of click than you need one function or two functions which only call one common function :) But it is no problem - real problem is: every double click generate also single click.

Comment: so essentially this can't be solved. I guess ill start looking at others GUIS

Comment: Only solution is to wait in single click (using after) for double click - if there was no double click than you can run single click.

Comment: In answer to other question I made function which recognize left and right button click at the same time as one event.

Comment: I will think about this problem tommorow

Comment: Thank you, im gonna go back and look at your other code, and ill check back tomorrow

Comment: Done. It was easer than I thought. `click()` now print `single click` or `double click` never both. Eventually in `after()` you can change time to get better result.