# Behavior of <FocusOut> event of ttk.Combobox

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, events, combobox

In order to edit the elements of a `ttk.Treeview` I searched to have a `ttk.Entry` and a `ttk.ComboBox` poping up from the treeview whenever the user double clicks on it.

For that, I found a `tkk.Entry` derived class, to which I made a few adaptations to suit my needs (it may also be that who wrote it originally didn't finish it).
It seems this one is working fine.
Then I derived a class from `ttk.ComboBox` inspired in the previous one.

Here's the code, with both classes, the treeview and a main window for everything to work.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class EntryPopup(ttk.Entry):

    def __init__(self, parent, iid, col, text, **kw):
        super().__init__(parent, **kw)
        self.tv = parent
        self.iid = iid
        self.col = col

        self.insert(0, text)
        self.select_range(0, tk.END)

        self.focus_force()
        self.bind("<Return>", self.on_return)
        self.bind("<Escape>", lambda *ignore: self.destroy())
        self.bind("<FocusOut>", self.on_return)

    def on_return(self, event):
        if self.col == '#0':
            self.tv.item(self.iid, text=self.get())
        else:
            self.tv.set(self.iid, self.col, self.get())
        self.destroy()


class ComboPopup(ttk.Combobox):

    def __init__(self, parent, iid, col, **kw):
        super().__init__(parent, **kw)
        self.tv = parent
        self.iid = iid
        self.col = col
        self.set(self.tv.set(iid, col))

        self.focus()
        self.bind("<Escape>", lambda *ignore: self.destroy())
        self.bind("<FocusOut>", self.focus_out())
        self.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", self.new_selection())

    def new_selection(self):
        self.tv.set(self.iid, self.col, self.get())

    def focus_out(self):
        self.new_selection()
        self.destroy()


class App(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.entryPopup = None

        # Create Treeview
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self.parent, column=('A', 'B'), selectmode='browse', height=7)
        self.tree.pack(expand=True, fill='both', side='top')

        # Setup column heading
        self.tree.heading('#0', text=' Items', anchor='center')
        self.tree.heading('#1', text=' A', anchor='center')
        self.tree.heading('#2', text=' B', anchor='center')

        self.tree.bind("<Double-Button>", self.on_double_click)

        self.tree.insert('', 'end', text="First item", value=("A's value", "B's value"))
        self.tree.insert('', 'end', text="Second item", value=("A's value", "B's value"))

    def on_double_click(self, event):
        # What row and column was clicked on
        rowid = self.tree.identify_row(event.y)
        column = self.tree.identify_column(event.x)

        # get cell position info
        x, y, width, height = self.tree.bbox(rowid, column)

        # y-axis offset
        pady = height / 2

        # place Entry popup properly
        if column == '#0':
            text = self.tree.item(rowid, 'text')
            self.entryPopup = EntryPopup(self.tree, rowid, column, text)
        else:
            self.entryPopup = ComboPopup(self.tree, rowid, column, values=("A", "b", "3"))
        self.entryPopup.place(x=x, y=y + pady, width=width, height=1.25 * height, anchor='w')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry('900x600+300+300')
    App(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

So if the user double clicks on a cell of the first column, a `EntryPopup` object is produced there, if in another column, it's a `ComboPopup` one.

In the `EntryPopup` object, on an `<Escape>` event, the object is just destroyed, without changing anything; on a `<Return>` or `<FocusOut>` whatever changes were made are retained.
The reason for which I think it is important to do it also on `<FocusOut>` is that that's what happens when the user proceeds to another cell (by clicking it, for example).

Now in the `ComboPopup` object the `<FocusOut>` event is a problem.
Apparently, this event is triggered when the user tries to access the combo box, in the first place, and that raises an error that I cannot understand:

> File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1340, in _bind
> return self.tk.call(what + (sequence,))
> _tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".!treeview.!combopopup"

On the other hand, if I set `<FocusOut>` to behave just like `<Escape>` then no error arises, but I also never retain the choice of the user, in the combo box.
Finally, if I set it as the `<Return>` event, no error arises and the value that was chosen is retained, but the combobox remains there, a situation in which I can have one combobox for each cell, and they only go away if the `<Escape>` event is triggered, again loosing the data introduced.

I've been around this for a while and I think that I can't get a solution on my own.
Maybe there is an easy fix for this?

Comment: `self.bind("<FocusOut>", self.focus_out())` _immediately_ calls `self.focus_out()`.

Comment: @BryanOakley Yes, I kind of refer to that in the third paragraph after the code. The problem is that I really must deal with `<FocusOut>` somehow, or nothing works...

Comment: You can bind to `<FocusOut>`, but you need to do so properly. Are you aware of the difference between `self.bind("<FocusOut>", self.focus_out())` and `self.bind("<FocusOut>", self.focus_out)`? (the same problem exists for several of your bindings)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/5767228/7432

Comment: @BryanOakley Not really. I sometimes don't know if I should add parentheses or not. In this case, I tried both ways, but without them, I think I got an error.

Comment: @BryanOakley I just tried `self.bind("<FocusOut>", self.focus_out)` (without parentheses) and it doesn't give any error, but it doesn't do anything either.

Comment: You must be doing something wrong. When I make that same change, `self.focus_out` does get called. It throws an error because it doesn't accept the `event` parameter, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I'got a satisfactory way of going around the problem I faced with the code in this post.
What I mean with a way around is that I didn't exactly fix the `<FocusOut>` behavior, but rather replaced it with a call from the treeview for any mouse click or double click.

Notice that it's not obvious how to control both a 'click' and a 'double click' event on the same widget, since in a double click there are two single clicks.
Fortunately, I found [this answer which addresses that problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24601715/14937105) (I found it odd that it didn't have any upvote before mine one).

With all the above adapted for this new approach, the resulting code is

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class EntryPopup(ttk.Entry):

    def __init__(self, parent, iid, col, text, **kw):
        super().__init__(parent, **kw)
        self.tv = parent
        self.iid = iid
        self.col = col

        self.insert(0, text)
        self.select_range(0, tk.END)

        self.focus_force()
        self.bind("<Return>", self.on_return)
        self.bind("<Escape>", self.on_escape)

    def on_return(self, event):
        self.close()

    def on_escape(self, event):
        self.destroy()

    def close(self):
        if self.col == '#0':
            self.tv.item(self.iid, text=self.get())
        else:
            self.tv.set(self.iid, self.col, self.get())
        self.destroy()


class ComboPopup(ttk.Combobox):

    def __init__(self, parent, iid, col, **kw):
        super().__init__(parent, **kw)
        self.tv = parent
        self.iid = iid
        self.col = col
        self.old_text = self.tv.set(iid, col)
        self.set(self.old_text)

        self.focus()
        self.bind("<Escape>", self.on_escape)
        self.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", self.new_selection)
        self.bind("<Return>", self.on_return)

    def new_selection(self, event=None):
        self.tv.set(self.iid, self.col, self.get())

    def on_return(self, event):
        self.close()

    def on_escape(self, event):
        self.tv.set(self.iid, self.col, self.old_text)
        self.destroy()

    def close(self):
        self.new_selection()
        self.destroy()


class App(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.cellPopup = None
        self.single_click = False

        # Create Treeview
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self.parent, column=('A', 'B'), selectmode='browse', height=7)
        self.tree.pack(expand=True, fill='both', side='top')

        # Setup column heading
        self.tree.heading('#0', text=' Items', anchor='center')
        self.tree.heading('#1', text=' A', anchor='center')
        self.tree.heading('#2', text=' B', anchor='center')

        self.tree.bind("<Double-Button-1>", lambda event: self.on_click(event, 101))
        self.tree.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event: self.on_click(event, 1))

        self.tree.insert('', 'end', text="First item", value=("A's value 1", "B's value 1"))
        self.tree.insert('', 'end', text="Second item", value=("A's value 2", "B's value 2"))

    def destroy_cell_popup(self):
        if self.single_click:
            self.single_click = False
            if self.cellPopup and self.cellPopup.winfo_exists():
                self.cellPopup.close()
                self.cellPopup = None

    def on_click(self, event, extra=None):
        """ Executed, when a row is single or double-clicked.
        Opens EntryPopup or ComboPopup above the item's column,
        so it is possible to select text """
        if extra == 1:
            self.single_click = True
            self.parent.after(200, self.destroy_cell_popup)
            return
        elif extra == 101:
            self.single_click = False
            if self.cellPopup and self.cellPopup.winfo_exists():
                self.cellPopup.close()
                self.cellPopup = None

        # What row and column was clicked on
        rowid = self.tree.identify_row(event.y)
        column = self.tree.identify_column(event.x)

        # Check if the double click was on some row or empty space
        if rowid == '':
            return

        # get cell position info
        x, y, width, height = self.tree.bbox(rowid, column)

        # y-axis offset
        pady = height / 2

        # place Entry popup properly
        if column == '#0':
            text = self.tree.item(rowid, 'text')
            self.cellPopup = EntryPopup(self.tree, rowid, column, text)
        else:
            self.cellPopup = ComboPopup(self.tree, rowid, column, values=("A", "b", "3"))
        self.cellPopup.place(x=x, y=y + pady, width=width, height=1.25 * height, anchor='w')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry('900x600+300+300')
    App(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

It seems to be working flawlessly.
For now, anyway...